# Can we use C# function in ClientTemplate inside Telerik extension grid?

Tags: telerik-mvc

I have a telerik extension grid. I have to generate a html link based on various scenarios and show that link in inside the grid column. I have implemented it successfully using the Template.
But I am having issue doing the same thing inside ClientTemplate for that column. I am trying to use String.IsNullOrEmpty() and another c# function inside ClientTemplate. I suspect the issue is due to trying to use these function inside ClientTemplate. Is it doable?

```
.ClientTemplate("<#if(IsUrgent){ #>" +                                                       "<# if( #> " + String.IsNullOrEmpty("<#= AssignedUser1 #>") + " ||" +  String.IsNullOrEmpty("<#=AssignedUser2 #>") + "<#) { #>"  + 
      "<a class='urgent-row' href=" + Url.Action("AssignUserDialog", "User", new { userNo = "<#= UserNo #>" }) + "><#= UserNo #></a>" +
        "<# } else { #>" +
   "<a class=''    href=" + Url.Action("Index", "User", new { userNo = "<#=   UserNo #>" }) + "><#= UserNo #></a>" +

  "<# } #>"     
"<# }
```

I searched over similar issues but only found examples where ClientTemplate used javascript functions, not C# functions.

Is is possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could just call a Javascript function that would call an action, using Jquery's $.ajax which would return the string you want inside the ClientTemplate.